# A unique syntax to slice pandas dataframe columns either over a string or an integer

Tags: python, pandas, function, types

I want to write a function that allows user to slice the columns of `pandas` dataframe either using a column name (string) or the index of the column (integer). Is there a way to avoid ugly syntax with a test of the function argument type, as follows?

```
import pandas as pd

def foo(df, col_to_slice_on):
    if isinstance(col_to_slice_on, str):
        return df.loc[:, col_to_slice_on]
    elif isinstance(col_to_slice_on, int):
        return df.iloc[:, col_to_slice_on]
'''
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0,1,2], 'B': [3,4,5]})
foo1 = foo(df, 'A')
foo2 = foo(df, 0)
'''
```

Apologies if it is obvious to everyone else.

Thank you.

Comment: Your self_def function is good for this type task, no build-in function for this in panda

Comment: FYI: there used to be a method `xi`, but it is deprecated since padnas 0.20.0, as described here in the pandas [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html)